# I want to create replica of mysql database on another server

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, mysql

I want to create a replica of mysql on another server so that when I move my site from one server to another, So that I cannot miss any record. As my database is constantly updating, I want to create replica so that I cant miss any records.

I am using `phpmyadmin` and I have different database in it. So I want to move only one database from one server to another.

Please help me regarding this..

How can I move my database from one server to another without missing records. Please guide me step wise procedure. I am using `Whm and cpanel.`

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/setting_up_replication.html will help you

Comment: I am new in linux.. Can you pls help me how we do this in lyman language.. and explain me the step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mobile, and can elaborate if need be, but [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/import-and-export-databases-using-phpmyadmin/) should explain.

You should be able to simply export the entire database as SQL, and then on the new server, execute that statement.

---

### Update:

When you log into phpMyAdmin, you have databases along the left hand side. Select the database you want to make a copy of. Click on the 'Export' tab along the top.[image: Export and Custom]
Make sure it is set to Custom, and then scroll down and check the box that says 'Add Create Database'[image: AddDatabase]

Go to the bottom and choose 'Go.'

It should create a .sql file that starts with

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.9
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
--
...
a ton of data and insert statements here
```

Make sure to note the location of that file.

GO TO THE NEW SERVER, in phpMyadmin, and choose import. Again, make sure that SQL is selected, and then browse to the .sql file you just created.
[image]

Click 'GO', and you should be all set.

Comment: i am sorry.. but i dont get from this.

Comment: you share me to download and upload sql file from one server to another.. but in between there are lot of transaction would be happening. how will i get those reocrd which is happening in between that..

Comment: The only way I can see how to deal with that, is to move that data later.

Comment: Write to Database A. Copy database A to B, while still writing to A. Once B is set up, switch everything to write to B. Then go back and copy any missed information from A to B.

Comment: Just because you have made a copy of the database on a new server, does not mean you cannot write to the old one. Until it is deleted obviously.

Comment: How I can Do that.. and How can I know.? I missed any record or not.. Because I am working on important sites. every record matter...

Comment: i know i will write untill i remove it. But When i am shifting it... I am scared that i miss any record.